# Create island mesh grid with drawn vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I am trying to create some terrain, specifically in the shape of an island.

I drew an outline of the island with a single vert. I want to create a mesh so there can be different levels of height on the terrain.

**Vertex Outline Example:**

[image]

What I tried first was using a plane that was subdivided many times and then intersecting the plane with my filled vertex outline with the Boolean modifier. This worked to some extent, however I ended up with a bunch of ngons around the edges of the outline. Secondly, I read here saying to possibly try the grid fill option, but I believe the geometry isn't setup to work with that as it did nothing.

What is a good way to generate a custom shape mesh in the form of an island so that I can apply and shape terrain on the top surface?

*Update In Regards to Mr.Zaks Answer*
It's importing into Unity 3D as one mesh, but in pieces. This is because Unity 3D has a 64k vert limit. You can correct this by either lowering the vert count or creating tiles of your mesh into 4 pieces. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

[image]

Comment: @MrZak When I add the remesh modifer, I don't see it making any changes. Any idea?

Comment: @MrZak It appears the problem was the surface was too flat. So I extruded it upwards and the remesh modifier properly recalculated the topology. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make that profile with more or less even topology suitable for further landscape editing; one is to use curve's 2D type to fill the outline and then once converted to mesh edit the topology.

On the image below, from left to right:

- original outline created as mesh;
- outline converted to curve, its Z axis is clamped because it's set up as 2D curve but it's filled with faces;
- outline converted to mesh and has 2 modifiers - [Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) and [Remesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html#remesh-modifier). The first one to give thickness to the outline as [Remesh doesn't work with meshes without any thickness](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html#usage), the second one to generate new topology. Adding thickness is possible without modifier, e.g by extruding curve in the Geometry scroll.

[image: screenshot-outlines-evolution]

Note that those tiny quads in the corners might not be desired as they can cause problems especially with any kind of subdivisions; it's best to change them before giving outline any thickness.

Comment: This works perfectly and as desired, but when I import into Unity 3D, it's showing strangely as two separate meshes and the faces are a bit messed up. Is there a way in blender to ensure it's all combined back into one single mesh?

Comment: @CodingGuru in general make sure to recalculate normals (Ctrl+N with all selected) and check non-manifold elements before exporting. It could make problem clearer if you show a screenshot of the mesh.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! This was so helpful. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Actually, they are still importing in Unity 3D as separate pieces still for some reason. Screenshot attached to the main thread.

Comment: I believe this is an issue with Unity 3D rather than Blender, as Unity has a 64k vertex limit for one mesh. So I simply lowered the vert count. Thanks for all your help!